# Lista enlazada último nodo pasar a ser el primero

Tags: java, lista

Modifiqué el código para que al ingresar los nodos de la lista, el ultimo nodo pase a ser el primero, el que esta de primero pase a ser el segundo.

```
package nodos;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
*
* @author x2010s
*/
public class Nodos {
    public String nombre;

    public Nodos nodosiguiente;
    public Nodos nodosanterior;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Se ingresa la cantidad de nodos a crear */    
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de nodos a ingresar");
        int n, contador = 0;
        n = leer.nextInt();

        /* El dato del nodo es ingresado */
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            Nodos nodo = new Nodos();
            System.out.print("ingrese la nombre ");
            nodo.nombre = leer.next();
         
            /* El nodo es creado*/
            if (contador == 0) {
                nodo.nodosiguiente = null;
                contador++;
            } else {
                nodo.nodosiguiente = nodo;
                contador++;
            }    
         
            /* Coloca de primero el último nodo creado*/
            if (contador == n) {
                nodo.nodosiguiente = nodo;
            }
            nodo.nodosanterior = null;
            for (i = 1; i < contador; i++) {
                nodo.nodosanterior = nodo;
                nodo.nodosiguiente = null;
            }

            /* La lista enlazada es imprimida*/
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                System.out.println("nombre " + nodo.nombre + "\n");
                System.out.println("apuntador " + nodo.nodosiguiente + "\n");    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando ingreso la cantidad de 3 nodos, solo me pide una vez los datos. Cuando imprime el único nodo, lo imprime tres veces.

Answer (score 1):

En tu código hay bastantes errores, pero no te preocupes, es normal cuando se está empezando.

En primer lugar, declaras una clase `Nodos`, y la lista de nodos se maneja en el `main`. Es buena práctica separar el `main` en una clase diferente de la clase en donde defines la estructura que va a ser manejada, pero esto en sí no es un error. Además, también es buena práctica que una clase tenga nombre en singular cuando se vaya a referir a entidades individuales, el plural solo si va a ser una colección de elementos, por lo que la mejor práctica sería llamar a tu clase `Nodo`, en singular, pero esto tampoco es un error desde el punto de vista del lenguaje.

El error principal es que no separas las diferentes acciones dentro del `main`.

Primero lees el número de nodos que deseas ingresar, y entras en un bucle para ir leyendo los diferentes nodos. Y dicho bucle tiene a `i` como variable de control. Pero dentro del bucle haces otro bucle anidado utilizando la misma variable de control `i`, y la inicializas a 1. Previamente, al leer el primer nodo, `contador` se pone a `1`, por lo que dicho bucle anidado no se ejecuta nunca, porque `i < contador` se evalúa como falso.

```
// No se ejecuta nunca porque i == contador
for (i = 1; i < contador; i++) {
    nodo.nodosanterior = nodo;
    nodo.nodosiguiente = null;
}
```

Entonces vuelves a hacer otro bucle anidado al principal, y vuelves a utilizar la variable de control `i`, inicializándola a 1, y ejecutando iteraciones hasta que `i == n + 1`. Y en todas las iteraciones vas a imprimir el mismo nodo, que es el único que hay.

```
// n iteraciones donde se imprime el nodo leído en la iteración actual del bucle principal
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    System.out.println("nombre " + nodo.nombre + "\n");
    System.out.println("apuntador " + nodo.nodosiguiente + "\n");    
}
```

Entonces termina la iteración del bucle principal que declaró a `i`, pero como ahora mismo `i == n + 1`, la condición de continuación se evalúa como falsa, y se sale del bucle sin leer ningún nodo más.

```
// Se ejecuta una sola vez porque modificas i dentro del mismo bucle hasta que i == n + 1
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    Nodos nodo = new Nodos();
    System.out.print("ingrese la nombre ");
    nodo.nombre = leer.next();
    // ...
```

Para solucionarlo intenta separar las diferentes partes de tu código de una manera más lógica, pero sobre todo, no modifiques las variable de control de un bucle `for` dentro del bucle. Cada bucle debería tener su propia variable de control.

De manera resumida, utilizando funciones que habría que implementar más tarde:

```
public class Nodo {
    // ...
    public static void main(string[] args) {
        int n = leerEntero();    // Número de nodos a leer y añadir a la lista
        Nodo lista = null;       // Lista inicialmente nula

        // Bucle de creación de la lista
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {    // Alternativa: for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            Nodo nodo = leerNodo();      // Instrucciones para leer un solo nodo
            if (lista == null) lista = nodo;    // Si no había lista, asignar el nodo inicial como cabeza de la lista
            else lista.addNodo(nodo);    // Se añade el nodo a la lista
        }

        // Bucle independiente para la impresión (es una i diferente a la del bucle de arriba)
        Nodo nodoActual = lista;    // Variable para recorrer la lista de nodos (inicialmente la cabeza de la lista)
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            nodoActual.imprimir();  // Se imprime el nodo actual
            nodoActual = nodoActual.siguiente;    // Se avanza en el recorrido
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Para cualquier interesado, disculpas por responder a una pregunta tan antigua. Me apareció como pregunta con actividad reciente y no verifiqué la fecha de publicación.

Comment: A todos nos ha pasado, el robot que revisa preguntas sin respuesta aceptadas la volvió a subir

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que tienes el framento utilizado para imprimir dentro del `for` que pide los datos, estaria imprimiendo cada vez que ingresas un dato, debe quedar algo asi:

```
for (int i =1; i <= n; i++){
        Nodos nodo = new Nodos();
        System.out.print("ingrese la nombre ");
        nodo.nombre=leer.next();
        ...
}
//aqui iria el metodo imprimir nodo...
```

ademas tienes otros errores, debes revisar tu codigo mejor